# Is there a property in micrometer than can disable sending SFx metrics?

Tags: monitoring, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, spring-micrometer, apm

I am working on a spring-boot project that has SignalFx (APM) instrumented for monitoring, instrumentation is done using micrometer and actuator.
I don't want metrics to be sent to SFx when I run application on local i.e. when my profile is set to `local`.
Is there a property that can be used to disable metrics being sent from local?
I have a facility to configure profile specific properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.signalfx.SignalFxMetricsExportAutoConfiguration` in `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure` module [Available Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/signalfx/SignalFxMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.java)

This class loads beans relevant for SignalFx.

It loads only if a property: `management.metrics.export.signalfx.enabled` has a value `true` or not defined at all.

So in profile local you can create `application-local.properties` file that will contain:

```
management.metrics.export.signalfx.enabled=false
```

Of course the same is possible with yaml based configurations.